# how to tell if a vector field in the space is conservative

Tags: calculus

so suppose we have a vector field $f: R^3 \to R^3 $. How can I tell if it is conservative.

lets take a simple example. what if $f(x,y,z) = y \hat{i} + z \hat{j} + x \hat{k} $. How can I tell if $f$ is conservative?

Comment: As long as the field is defined and continuous in _all of_ $\Bbb R^3$ (or some region of it without holes), then $f$ is conservative iff the [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) of $f$ is $0$.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ConservativeVectorField.aspx

Comment: @Arthur shouldn't it be differentiable too?

Comment: @Dmoreno Yes, that too. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It has scalar potential
2. $\oint\vec{f}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{s}=0$
3. $\nabla\times\vec{f}=\left(\frac{\partial f_z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial f_y}{\partial z},\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial f_z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial y}\right)=0$

All these conditions should be equivalent, but for the third one the field has to be differentiable. But it is usually the easiest to compute. The first one is good when you see you can find a scalar field, which satisfies the condition
$$\nabla\varphi=-\vec{f}$$

Good example of conservative field is the gravitational field. The work you have to do when you move something in space from one place to another is equivalent to the difference of potential between the two places.

edit:
The integral condition means, that whatever path you choose, you have done no work if the path is closed (i.e. you return to the place where you started). To use this statement you would have to prove that for all pathes the work is zero

In your case the rotation of the field is
$$\left(1,-1,-1\right)$$
so it's not conservative